# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to reach sites.

[image]

Also I have this error on logs. Is there any opinion?

```
UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/extensions: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config line 157) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.  File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))    
 at System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)    
 at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    
 at System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    
 at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ExtensionElementCollection.EnforceUniqueElement(ExtensionElement element)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ExtensionElementCollection.BaseAdd(ConfigurationElement element)    
 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement(String elementName, XmlReader reader)    
 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, Boolean serializeCollectionKey)    
 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, Boolean serializeCollectionKey)    
 at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.CreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)    
 at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader, String filename, Int32 line)         -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.GetProfileProperties()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()
```

Also I found this thread

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345913/access-denied-errors-after-installing-july-2018-security-rollup-update

Comment: Do you have custom solutions / web part in page

Comment: Nope, just SharePoint 2010 template and page. I'm getting this error from every site, subsite and pages.